# Ошибка в атрибуте запроса JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

В процессе разработки простого spring mvc проекта возникла ошибка в jsp. Добавленный в modelAttribute объект "book" недоступен в jsp.
BookController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    public BookController() {
    }
    //Остальные методы

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String addBook(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book) {
        if (book.getId() == 0){
            this.bookService.addBook(book);

        } else{
            this.bookService.updateBook(book);
        }
        return "redirect:/books/list";
    }

    //остальные методы
    }
```

books_page.jsp:

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/books/add" ></c:url>

<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="book">
    <table>
        <c:if test="${!empty book.title}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="id">
                        <spring:message text="ID"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="title">
                    <spring:message text="Title"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
```

Ошибка:

```
04-Feb-2018 13:03:17.592 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] 
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.doStartTag Neither 
BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'book' available as request attribute
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'book' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:118)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.books_005fpage_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f1(books_005fpage_jsp.java:518)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.books_005fpage_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(books_005fpage_jsp.java:250)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.books_005fpage_jsp._jspService(books_005fpage_jsp.java:167)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: `Добавленный в modelAttribute объект "book" недоступен в jsp` . Ок, а как и где Вы добавляете этот объект?

Comment: Покажите метод отображающий форму, проблема в нём.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Форма отображается сразу при загрузке страницы, а её адрес прописан в spring-config.xml . Я предполагал, что с этой формой связан метод addBook, который я привёл сверху, видимо, я ошибся?

Comment: @MrFylypenko Не подумал про это. Внутри метода addBook  должно быть добавление этого объекта? Разные видел версии, не знаю, какая верная, приведите пожалуйста пример, как можно переписать мой метод?

Comment: Если jsp-страницу отображает не контроллер, то никакой связи нет.

Comment: @lexx.step проблема в методе отображающий форму, как указали выше. В вопросе указан метод добавления (post), а где метод (get) который отображает пустую форму?

Comment: @MrFylypenko хмм, странно, не видел ни в одном туториале такого, у Вас есть пример на гитхабе?

Comment: [Вот один из примеров](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation) , Вам нужно в этой строке `<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="book">` заменить `commandName` на `modelAttribute` , а вот как книга попадает на эту форму, для меня загадка, в вопросе нет примера кода. А по ошибке [смотрите также сюда](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-xxx-available-as-request-attribute/)